# Which is faster, performing a ternary operator or casting an enum to a float?

Tags: c#, performance

I have an enum called facing

```
public enum Facing
{
    Right = 0,
    Left = 1
}
```

I have an object positioned such that 0 degrees of rotation is right, and 180 degrees is left. To ensure it is facing the correct way, I can do one of two things:

```
this.rotation(this.facing == Facing.Left ? 180f : 0f);
```

or, I could be cheeky and do something like this:

```
this.rotation((float)this.facing * 180f);
```

There are things to consider such as branch prediction, I imagine, that would lean towards the ternary being faster. But in general, which would probably be faster?

P.S. I know that comparison to the enum is more readable, and likely what I'm going with either way. This is more to satiate my curiosity.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I guess the other half of my question is "why" one would be faster than the other.

Comment: Cast to `int`. I've never heard of casting an enum to `float` since they can only be represented by integral types. I'd expect the cast to fail. Fastest is going to depend on benchmarking. One version has a branch and the other doesn't which could *maybe* matter if you were running this code a million times but I'd bet the jitter is smart enough to optimize either version into about the same thing.

Comment: I think there are 2 ways to know which one runs faster: 1) You can compare both lines with a [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1) multiple times, and measure performance; The second way is to look at the CIL code and examine how many lines the 2 codes produce, and compare who produces the most lines to find out who can be more expensive in terms of performance.

Comment: Use a tool like sharplab.io to see what both get translated to A. In terms of lowered form of c#, B. The IL (intermediate language) the compiler generates and C. The assembly the jit will turn it into. Those will explain "why" either one may be "faster"... But in a simple program like this it wouldn't matter either way

Comment: Processors have a conditional-move instruction to avoid branches, CMOV on x86/x64.  But this code generates a floating point value, no cmov for that, so you do get the branch.  Makes it somewhat likely that the multiply is faster, if the branch prediction isn't effective.  It usually is, you can only truly profile it with real data.

Comment: So can I assume you are running this lines of code 1000s every second to actually see a difference between those? Is your code so highly optimized that this is your bottle neck and is worth investing time?

Comment: @RandRandom Again, mostly curious. There's no bottleneck.

Comment: This bit of code is probably insignificant compared to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran my own horses as per suggestion.

- I generated a list of 100,000,000 random "Facings"
- I run the list against the two methods

  - The order of the two methods is chosen at random
  - I record each result
- I repeat this process 10 times
- I take the average

With multiple runs of the above... both seem to take virtually the same amount of time. About 280 milliseconds for each batch of 100,000,000.

A very anticlimactic result.

EDIT: Interesting enough, the first batch always seems to have the cast take significantly more time, on the order of 100 milliseconds. But then the subsequent batches generally have the cast run faster enough to make the averages even.

P.S. The other thing I was wondering is "why is one faster than the other," but since both are the same I'm not sure what else to think about it.

Comment: @Marlonchosky The CIL code is not really important. More important is what the Jitter makes of it as I‘ve seen cases where the Jitter reduces a set of a dozen IL statements to just one or two CPU opcodes.

Comment: @ckuri are you sure about that?